# JavaScript, define a date for each created item, working with notes

Tags: javascript, html

I want time and date function in my Notes which will be saved by user. I tried but it will change for every notes whenever user try to add new note so the previous notes time is also changed. So what should i do ?

Here is my code:

```js
// function to show notes from local storage
function showNotes() {
  let notes = localStorage.getItem("notes");
  if (notes == null) {
    notesObj = [];
  } else {
    notesObj = JSON.parse(notes);
  }

  let html = "";
  notesObj.forEach(function (element, index, i, dayValue) {
    html += `
    
            <div class="noteCard card text-center mr-3 mb-3 border-dark" style="width: 344px;">
                    <div class="card-header bg-dark text-light">
                        Featured
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Note ${index + 1}</h5>
                        <p class="card-text"> ${element}</p>
                        <button id="${index}" onclick="deleteNote(this.id)" class="btn btn-outline-danger my-4">Delete Note</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer text-light bg-secondary">
                        ${(i.value = new Date().toLocaleTimeString([], {
                          hour: "2-digit",
                          minute: "2-digit"
                        }))}
                    </div>
                </div>`;
  });
  let notesElm = document.getElementById("notes");
  if (notesObj.length != 0) {
    notesElm.innerHTML = html;
  } else {
    notesElm.innerHTML = `
            <div class="card text-light bg-dark mb-3" style="width: 1130px;">
        <div class="card-header text-dark bg-warning"><b>Message For You!</b></div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text"><h3>Nothing to show! Use "Add a Note" section above to add notes.</h3> </p>
        </div>
        </div>`;
  }
}
```

```
// If user adds a note, add it to the localStorage
let addBtn = document.getElementById('addBtn');
addBtn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {

    let addTxt = document.getElementById("addTxt");
    if (addTxt.textLength == 0) {
        alert("Please write something in text box first!")
    }
    else {
        let notes = localStorage.getItem("notes");
        if (notes == null) {
            notesObj = [];
        }
        else {
            notesObj = JSON.parse(notes);
        }
        notesObj.push({text: addTxt.value, date : new Date()});
        localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notesObj));
        addTxt.value = "";
        // console.log(notesObj);
        showNotes();
    }
})
```

Comment: Can you show the function for adding a new Note, and maybe your HTML as well? Already I can tell that this line you have `new Date().toLocaleTimeString...` will give you the same time for every note, which is the time when  showing the notes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this to work, you need to change each note from being a string (the input text) to an object with a `text` field and a `date` field. The `text` will be the input text and the `date`, its creation time. Then the code for formatting and showing the date would be  `new Date(element.date).toLocaleTimeString...` instead of `new Date().toLocaleTimeString...`

Working Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/yousoumar/pen/VwXLddM?editors=1111) and the code below:

```js
function showNotes() {
  let notes = localStorage.getItem("notes");
  if (notes == null) {
    notesObj = [];
  } else {
    notesObj = JSON.parse(notes);
  }
console.log( notesObj)
  let html = "";
  notesObj.forEach(function (element, index, i, dayValue) {
    html += `
    
            <div class="noteCard card text-center mr-3 mb-3 border-dark" style="width: 344px;">
                    <div class="card-header bg-dark text-light">
                        Featured
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Note ${index + 1}</h5>
                        <p class="card-text"> ${element.text}</p>
                        <button id="${index}" onclick="deleteNote(this.id)" class="btn btn-outline-danger my-4">Delete Note</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer text-light bg-secondary">
                        ${(i.value = new Date(element.date).toLocaleTimeString([], {
                          hour: "2-digit",
                          minute: "2-digit"
                        }))}
                    </div>
                </div>`;
  });
  let notesElm = document.getElementById("notes");
  if (notesObj.length != 0) {
    notesElm.innerHTML = html;
  } else {
    notesElm.innerHTML = `
            <div class="card text-light bg-dark mb-3" style="width: 1130px;">
        <div class="card-header text-dark bg-warning"><b>Message For You!</b></div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text"><h3>Nothing to show! Use "Add a Note" section above to add notes.</h3> </p>
        </div>
        </div>`;
  }
}
```

```js
// If user adds a note, add it to the localStorage
let addBtn = document.getElementById('addBtn');
addBtn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {

    let addTxt = document.getElementById("addTxt");
    if (addTxt.textLength == 0) {
        alert("Please write something in text box first!")
    }
    else {
        let notes = localStorage.getItem("notes");
        if (notes == null) {
            notesObj = [];
        }
        else {
            notesObj = JSON.parse(notes);
        }
        notesObj.push({text: addTxt.value, date : new Date()});
        localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notesObj));
        addTxt.value = "";
        // console.log(notesObj);
        showNotes();
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

### Adding Date like this format dd/mm/yyyy

have to add `${i.value = new Date(element.date).toLocaleTimeString([],  {year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric', hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit' })}`

```
// If user adds a note, add it to the localStorage
let addBtn = document.getElementById('addBtn');
addBtn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {

    let addTxt = document.getElementById("addTxt");
    if (addTxt.textLength == 0) {
        alert("Please write something in text box first!")
    }
    else {
        let notes = localStorage.getItem("notes");
        if (notes == null) {
            notesObj = [];
        }
        else {
            notesObj = JSON.parse(notes);
        }
        notesObj.push({text: addTxt.value, date : new Date()});
        localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notesObj));
        addTxt.value = "";
        // console.log(notesObj);
        showNotes();
    }
})
```

---

```
// function to show notes from local storage
function showNotes() {
    let notes = localStorage.getItem('notes');
    if (notes == null) {
        notesObj = [];
    }
    else {
        notesObj = JSON.parse(notes);
    }

    let html = "";
    notesObj.forEach(function (element, index, i) {
        html += `

        <div class="noteCard card text-center mr-3 mb-3 border-dark" style="width: 344px;">
                <div class="card-header bg-dark text-light">
                    Featured
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Note ${index + 1}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text"> ${element.text}</p>
                    <button id="${index}" onclick="deleteNote(this.id)" class="btn btn-outline-danger my-4">Delete Note</button>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer text-light bg-secondary">
                    ${i.value = new Date(element.date).toLocaleTimeString([], 
                        {year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric', hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit' })}
                </div>
            </div>`;
    });
    let notesElm = document.getElementById('notes');
    if (notesObj.length != 0) {
        notesElm.innerHTML = html;
    }
    else {
        notesElm.innerHTML = `
        <div class="card text-light bg-dark mb-3" style="width: 1130px;">
    <div class="card-header text-dark bg-warning"><b>Message For You!</b></div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text"><h3>Nothing to show! Use "Add a Note" section above to add notes.</h3> </p>
    </div>
    </div>`
    }

}
```